# Insert a variable inside a string after it is defined

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM test_table ' .$sqljoin . $where . $order;
if (a>0){
$sqljoin = 'INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id';
}else{
$where = 'WHERE target=1'
}

//Add the new variable to the SQL-sentence...
```

And then add the new variable to the SQL-sentence. In that way I dont need to write the SQL-sentence so many times and I can add values after the start of SQL is defined?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not exactly like this - you need to define the variable before you can use it. Or just concat it dynamically, using a single variable. And of course use the right syntax.

Comment: This is obviously __not possible__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://php.net/sprintf):

```
// I assume you have already defined $order somewhere before this

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_table %s %s %s';

$sqljoin = '';
$where = '';

if (a>0){
    $sqljoin = 'INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id';
}else{
    $where = 'WHERE target=1'
}

$sql = sprintf($sql, $sqljoin, $where, $order);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
$order = 'ORDER BY column_name ASC' //or DESC

if ($a>0)
{
    $sql_append = 'INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id';
}
else
{
    $sql_append = 'WHERE target=1'
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_table ' . $sql_append . $order;
```